# 3D PDF acrobat javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, annotations, acrobat

I am using acrobat js to change the default mouse behaviour on 3D annotations. I have defined six primary views and I want the user to view the model from these views only. The default tumbling of the model with the mouse should be disabled. I want the user to still be able to make use of other functionality offered by the 3D annotation toolbar.

I thought of stopping the propagation of mouse event, so here's what I tried

```
myAnnotsQ13D = getAnnots3D(0)[0];
if(myAnnotsQ13D.activated){

  c3D = myAnnotsQ13D.context3D;
  mouseEventHandler = c3D.MouseEventHandler();
  mouseEventHandler.onMouseDown = true;
  mouseEventHandler.onMouseMove = true;
  mouseEventHandler.onMouseUp = true;

  mouseEventHandler.onEvent = function(event){
    event.stopAllDispatch = true;
  }
  c3D.runtime.addEventHandler( mouseEventHandler );
}
```

This code doesn't seem to do anything. I am still able to rotate the model with the mouse. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from linkedin 3DPDF forum, Works like a charm

```
myAnnotsQ13D = getAnnots3D(0)[0];
if(myAnnotsQ13D.activated){

  c3D = myAnnotsQ13D.context3D;
  c3D.runtime.overrideRotateTool = true; // add these two lines to disable mouse tumbling
  c3D.runtime.overrideSpinTool   = true;

  mouseEventHandler = c3D.MouseEventHandler();
  mouseEventHandler.onMouseDown = false;
  mouseEventHandler.onMouseMove = false;
  mouseEventHandler.onMouseUp   = true

  mouseEventHandler.onEvent = function(event){
     var field = getField("NoOfClicksIM");
     field.value = ++noOfClicksIM;
  }
  c3D.runtime.addEventHandler( mouseEventHandler );
}
```